# .NET Core SSL certificate database does not exist on Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I use mailkit in my asp core app and I try to send mail via tls 1.3 with StartTls option. Here is my code:

```
var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
                emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Tom", "sender"));
                emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", "receiver"));
                emailMessage.Subject = "la";
                emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
                {
                    Text = "lalala"
                };

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.lalala.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync("sender", "password");
                    await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);

                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }
```

On localhost it works perfectly. But I have two ubuntu servers. On the first server if didn't work at first and an error massage was: `Expected ',' instead of ''` And that's all. But somehow I could receive a massage that mailkit couldn't find a path /home/my user/.dotnet/... and when I created this folder an email was sent. I saw that in this folder were x509 certificates or something like this. Then I tried to deploy this project on another ubuntu server and again wasn't succeed. I completely forgot about this folder and created simple console app sending email and again received an error with path ~/.dotnet. I created the path and the console app worked! But not the main asp app. So I got stuck. I work with my not admin user on this server and dotnet works as user www-data. So can it be permission error? And the received error can't explain anything

Comment: The problem is really unrelated at all to MailKit, it's really a .NET Core SSL certificate database issue. Anyone using `SslStream` will have this problem.

Comment: @jstedfast, and how can I create it?

Comment: I guess you should use the mkdir command

Comment: @jstedfast, but I don't know what path I need to create

Comment: I am having similar issue. Were you able to sort it out?